# Wrapping imported construtor in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, promise, bluebird

I have the same problem as [Promisify imported class (constructor) with bluebird in ES6 + babel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31392273/6173391). The accepted answer seems to have a bug but I couldnt comment on that thread (not enough reputation points), so am creating a new question. The bug seems to be in:

```
var o = new lib.C(); // get object
o.then(function(data){
    // access data
});
```

I get a run-time error:

```
~/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:114
    return this._then(didFulfill, didReject, didProgress,
                ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at C.Promise.then (~/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:114:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/temp/jsex.js:367:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Can somebody post a working sample? Or point out if I'm missing something?

Comment: Notice that [you shouldn't do something that needs a promise in a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) anyway.

Comment: I agree, this smells off to me. Is there a reason you can't have a function on that class which returns the promise instead?

Comment: This was a bug in my code - try again :P

Comment: @Bergi, I'm using node-sqlite3 whose constructor opens the database also. Success or error is conveyed via a callback (if provided) or events. So I want to chain any calls to the successful opening (or failure) of the database. I understand that this is not a good idea but I dont have control over the code in question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, thanks for confirming, I'll checkout the updated code.